# How to insert a floating circle in the middle of the top of a div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a card created with bootstrap, and I need to find a way to insert a circle on the top of the card.

My code:(Demo in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de2Lpzrg/1/))

```
<style>
        .numberCircle {
            width: 39.6px;
            height: 39.6px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 21.6px;
            border: 2px solid #3498db;
            color:white;
            background:#3498db;

        }
</style>

<body style="margin:20px; padding:20px;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
          <div class="numberCircle">30</div>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick card description...</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

And this is the result that I expect:

[image]

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use absolute on the circle and position relative to the card body.

I forked your fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lgr5anuf/

```css
.numberCircle {
    width: 39.6px;
    height: 39.6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21.6px;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    color:white;
    background:#3498db;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}
        
.card-body {
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body style="margin:20px; padding:20px;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
                <div class="numberCircle">30</div>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick card description...</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out the `position` CSS property. It allows you to position your elements anywhere you want, may it be relative to the page or the it's parent element.

Here's the updated CSS:

```
.card-body {
    position: relative;
}

.numberCircle {
    width: 39.6px;
    height: 39.6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21.6px;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    color: white;
    background: #3498db;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: -20px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using `transform` on the circle. 
Also note that I changed your px-values to whole integers, there can't be a comma-pixel value. These values would be invalid anyhow.

```css
.numberCircle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  color:white;
  background:#3498db;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  line-height: 40px;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body" style="text-align:center">
          <div class="numberCircle">30</div>
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick card description...</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set your circle as `position:absolute;` so you can set it at the top and in the middle. 
For the left position you can use the `calc()`.

```
.numberCircle {
       position:absolute;
        top:-20px;/* half of his height */
        left:calc(50% - 20px);/*50% - half of his length*/
        width: 39.6px;
        height: 39.6px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 21.6px;
        border: 2px solid #3498db;
        color:white;
        background:#3498db;

    }
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqcn5rsh/)

Comment: Use left: 50% and translate x instead of using calc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help, put this in number circle css.

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: -20;
```

Comment: There is a fiddle, try it and see it doesn't work... -1 because of short incorrect answer

Comment: Why would you have a problem if it's short I can understand if it doesn't work.